# Amazon-S3 drive: move and copy not working with Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I am trying to write a function in my Laravel app that will rename a file on an S3 drive.

I have tried:

```
if(Storage::disk('s3')->exists($old_path)) {
    Storage::disk('s3')->move($old_path, $new_path);
}
```

but it does not do anything.

```
dd(Storage::disk('s3')->exists($old_path))
```

returns `True`

also

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put($full_path, file_get_contents($file));
Storage::disk('s3')->get($full_path);
```

both work fine!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was down to the polices allowed for the resource in my S3 bucket.

To solve it I had to allow the following actions:

`s3:GetObjectVersion`

`s3:DeleteObjectVersion`

`s3:PutObjectAcl`

`s3:GetObjectAcl`

So my policy looks something like this now:

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": "*",
    "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:GetObjectAcl",
        "s3:GetObjectVersion",
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:DeleteObjectVersion"
    ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::folder/path/*"
}
```

Comment: I also needed to add `s3:ReplicateObject` in order to get `Storage::move()` working.